# Matplotlib griddata fails

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to write a function which makes a contour plot from a text data file (or a numpy array) formatted as "x, y, z". However, when I try to use griddata to interpolate the data, I get a "type" error:

```
    if not len(x)==len(y)==len(z):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

This is my function:

```
def ContourPlot(datafile,columns=[0,1,2], nXvals=100, nYvals=100, title='', xlab='', ylab='', colormap='rainbow', contours=10):

        if type(datafile)==type(str()):
                try:
                        x, y, z = np.loadtxt(datafile, dtype='float', unpack=True, usecols=columns)
                except:
                        print "Can't open the input file!"
                        exit
        elif type(datafile)==np.ndarray:
                        x = datafile[0]
                        y = datafile[1]
                        z = datafile[2]
        else:
                        print "ERROR: You tried to pass data to the ContourPlot() function in a format it cannot read"
                        exit

        print type(x)

        xi = np.linspace(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), nXvals)
        yi = np.linspace(np.amin(y), np.amax(y), nYvals)
        zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
        norm = colors.Normalize(vmin = np.min(z), vmax = np.max(z), clip = False)
        pl.figure()
        pl.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 30, cmap = pl.get_cmap(colormap), norm =norm)
        CS = pl.contour(xi, yi, zi, colors = 'k',lw = 3, levels= contours)
        pl.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
        pl.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
        pl.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)
        pl.title(title, fontsize=17)
        pl.xlabel(xlab, fontsize=20)
        pl.ylabel(ylab, fontsize=20)
        pl.show()
```

I tried converting x, y, z to regular Python lists with the tolist() method, but it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you tell us how your data file looks like? Has it 3 columns or 3 rows? how are the values separated?

Comment: The error is telling you that one of x, y, z is a float, not a list (of floats). Maybe your file-read failed, maybe a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an older version of matplotlib? Where are you importing your griddata from? Have a look at the griddate function in your matplotlib/mlab.py file and look whether there is a line similar to

```
if not len(x)==len(y)==len(z):
    raise TypeError("inputs x,y,z must all be 1D arrays of the same length")
```

The current version at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py does not have this line any more but now checksthis way:

```
# Check input arguments.
x = np.asanyarray(x, dtype=np.float64)
y = np.asanyarray(y, dtype=np.float64)
z = np.asanyarray(z, dtype=np.float64)
if x.shape != y.shape or x.shape != z.shape or x.ndim != 1:
    raise ValueError("x, y and z must be equal-length 1-D arrays")
```

So an update to a more recent version might already solve your problem. In any case currently at least one of your x, y, z inputs is of type numpy.float64 and for some reason has no len().